# SSIS OnPreExecute Event Handler for Sequence Container firing multiple times

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a sequence container called "Extract".  Inside I have a 2 data flow tasks, and 1 execute sql task.  Neither of the data flow or execute sql tasks have event handlers created for them.  On the sequence container, I have created an execute sql task on the OnPreExecute event that logs 1 row in a "ProcessStep" table.  The problem I am running into is that there appears to be 4 records inserted into the database per run.  I assume that the event is being executed for the 3 tasks in the container and the container itself.  I tried turning the 3 tasks "DisableEventHandlers" property to true, and the LoggingMode property to disabled, but it is still is logging 4 records each time.  Any suggestions??

Comment: Instead of using Pre-Execute can you put the sql command in an execute sql task that precedes the container in the control flow?

Comment: This is the exact route I went with :)